# ASP.NET, PHP and Ruby on Rails applications running on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, ruby-on-rails, iis-7.5

We are about to get a new Windows 2008 R2 Server for development, testing and also as a "showroom" for clients.

We will need to deploy all kind of applications (ASP.NET, PHP and Ruby on Rails for instance).
Fortunately, IIS 7.5 is already capable of serving ASP.NET and PHP files.

- For Ruby on Rails what would be the best approach?
- Is it possible to have IIS to serve RoR files under port 80? (we have just 1 ip)
- If not, how would you setup things to avoid having to explicity type :port in URL?
- Is it possible to make use of IIS URL redirection to pass some requests to apache (port 81) so it can process the RoR requests with clean url (without :81). How?

Sorry if this question is already asked, but I didn't found some clear facts about it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes IIS is able to handle all of those and more all over the same port and same IP Address. To install Ruby see: http://ruslany.net/2008/08/ruby-on-rails-in-iis-70-with-url-rewriter/

You can also setup a reverse proxy to forward requests to Apache if needed using the Application Request Routing feature in IIS 7 http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting